# Possible to create class aliases dynamically?

Tags: raku

Got this class:

```
class Mass-lb is Mass {
    method new(Rat:D() $value = 1.0) {
        self.bless(
            :abbr('lb'),
            :base_value(453.59237),
            :$value,
        );
    }
}
```

I have created aliases like this:

```
class Mass-lbs is Mass-lb { }
class Mass-pound is Mass-lb { }
class Mass-pounds is Mass-lb { }
class Mass-pnds is Mass-lb { }
```

But I'd prefer to do something like this:

```
my @lb-syn = < lbs pounds pound pnds >;
for @lb-syn {
    EVAL 'class ::("Mass-$_") is Mass-lb {}';
}
```

This throws an error:

`Name ::("Mass-$_") is not compile-time known, and can not serve as a package name`

PHP has a built-in for creating aliases: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php

I couldn't find anything similar for raku.

Comment: Those are not aliases. Those are subclasses. Only instances constructed using the subclass constructors are going to be valid instances of the given subclass.

Comment: True, but I'm using them as if they are aliases. It's the only way I could find to accomplish it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In RakuAST there's a class that you can call to create a new type.  But that the RakuAST branch hasn't landed yet.

Until then, your approach using `EVAL` is valid, you just need to make it a bit simpler:

```
class Mass-lb { }
BEGIN "constant Mass-$_ = Mass-lb".EVAL
  for <lbs pounds pound pnds>;
my $mlb = Mass-lbs.new;
```

1. Make sure the aliases are created at `BEGIN` time.
2. No need to subclass, you can use a `constant` for aliasing.
3. Since `constant`s are `our` by default, they're visible outside of the `EVAL`.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could use raku Physics::Unit and Physics::Measure...

```
use Physics::Unit;
use Physics::Measure :ALL;

# define a new custom Unit
Unit.new( defn => 'lbm', names => <Mass-lb Mass-lbs Mass-pound Mass-pounds Mass-pnds> );

say GetUnit('Mass-lbs').names;      #[Mass-lb Mass-lbs Mass-pound Mass-pounds Mass-pnds]

# use the Unit in a Measure 
my $mass = ♎️'42 Mass-pnds';
say $mass;                          #42Mass-lb
say $mass.^name;                    #(..Mass) ...class name

# convert to another Unit
my $kgm = $mass.in: 'kg';
say $kgm;                           #19.05087954kg

# convert back 
say $kgm.in: 'Mass-pound';          #42Mass-lb

# raku Rats mean that the back conversion is identical
say $kgm cmp $mass;                 #Same

# with % or abs Error
my $mass2 = ♎️'42 Mass-pnds ±3%';
say $mass2;                         #42Mass-lb ±1.26
say $mass2.in: 'kg';                #19.05087954kg ±0.5715263862
```

More info at github [Physics::Unit](https://github.com/p6steve/raku-Physics-Unit) and [Physics::Measure](https://github.com/p6steve/raku-Physics-Measure)...

Comment: Yeah, saw that. But I wanted to roll my own for fun. I'm rusty an physics, need to get better with Raku, and have some niche use cases (mostly using of molecular weights).

Comment: Sorry ... don't want to spoil the Ofun! Actually I chose this as my first module project because it combines a lot of raku concepts (types, Grammars, math function overloads and so on) so the whole area of physical quantities is good raku fodder. Hopefully you are OK leaving this here as it may help to signppost other seekers. There was a also recent convo about molecular weights [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/rakulang/comments/uqumkc/raku_chemistrystoichiometry/i8yqb1f/?context=3). Enjoy!

Comment: Oh, yeah. No problem. I'm trying not to look at yours until I'm done. I plan on rolling my own and then comparing it to yours to see where I might improve (or maybe have improved upon yours, if I'm lucky). I'm finding it's a good little project to cut my teeth on. One of those things that seems simple but kind of tricky to write maintainable code especially if you are out of practice with physics/math, like me. Good exercise.